# Modularizing a Java Project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, module, java-platform-module-system, modularization

I have four Java packages in Eclipse: augustus, caligula, julius, and nero. I want to place augustus and caligula in a module. I want to place julius and nero in another module. How do I go about doing that?

I tried creating a "Module1" folder under the "src" source folder to hold augustus and caligula. And I tried creating a "Module2" folder under "src" source folder to hold julius and nero. However, these folders are automatically turned into packages in Eclipse.

Then I tried creating a "Module1" source folder to hold augustus and caligula. And I tried creating a "Module2" source folder to hold julius and nero. However, it seems Eclipse allows only one module-info.java file. In other words, I can't put a module-info.java file in each source folder.

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/java/post/how-to-develop-modules-with-eclipse-ide

Comment: I will read that article. Thank you.

Comment: Each module has to be a project of its own, as it has its own dependencies. Prefer self-contained modules by having each module have its own resources and settings that are synchronized rather than shared.

Comment: @MadProgrammer That's at least outdated. For example, in the launch configuration, no _VM arguments_ has and should be configured.

Comment: @howlger My point is, SO isn't the first place to seek answers

Comment: @MadProgrammer The tutorial might be the reason for a couple of weird questions asked on Stack Overflow. The first place to look for help about specific software is the documentation of the software itself, not blog posts that are that old.

Comment: @howlger True, and again, my point - not proof of investigation to solve the issue was provied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each Java Project holds a single module in the Java Platform Module System. I primarily used this video as a resource: [Creating a Multi-Module Maven Project](https://youtu.be/zVwUy08SFnA?feature=shared). However, a book titled "The Java Module System" by Nicolai Parlog can help understand the underlying theories behind the system.

---

Here is a tutorial on how I was able to solve my problem:

### Create a Maven Project

This parent project holds all the modules (child projects). Press the New button ⇒ Maven ⇒ Maven Project ⇒ press the Next button ⇒ check "Create a simple project" ⇒ press the Next button ⇒

```
Group Id: org.name 
Artifact Id: RomanEmperors
Version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Packaging: pom
```

⇒ press the Finish button.

### Create a Maven Module

Press the New button ⇒ Maven ⇒ Maven Module ⇒ press the Next button ⇒ check "Create a simple project" ⇒

```
Module Name: MavenModuleName1
Parent Project: RomanEmperors
```

⇒ press the Finish button.

### Create a module-info.java File

Right-click on your Maven Module ⇒ Configure ⇒ Create module-info.java ⇒ "Project requires compliance level of 9 or above. Do you want to change project compliance and JRE to 20?" press the Yes button ⇒

```
Module name: module1
```

Note. By convention, module names usually start with a lowercase letter. ⇒ press the Create button.

### Create a Package

Right-click on "src/main/java" ⇒ New ⇒ Package ⇒

```
Name: augustus
```

Note. By convention, package names usually start with a lowercase letter. ⇒ press the Finish button.

---

Then, repeat the steps to create the other modules and packages.